# How can I determine if a program that does not normally access the Internet is accessing the Internet

Tags: networking, display, internet

I need to know if a program accesses the Internet.
I want to view a log to see if a program ever accesses the Internet while it is running.
Preferably not having to watch a screen but rather look at a network log.
All of the information I have found on the Internet only shows active connections, so programs not actively accessing the Internet are not shown.
Even netstat -b misses programs that quickly access the Internet.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Are you concerned about an attack or virus, or is the program innocuous and valid? If the program is not actively trying to hide it will not just "quickly" access the internet, and the connections it opens will remain open for an extended period of time until it times out.

Comment: I have searched the Internet for solutions. I have tried Wireshark, netstat, fiddler. So far, all solutions only show active connections. I would like to know if a program occasionally uses the Internet. It may only briefly use the Internet to send data.

Comment: try resetting your firewall rules and see if you get a notification about the program wanting internet access?

Comment: You still haven't explained the basis of your concern, why you're worried about this. If you've looked at Netstat and Wireshark, and you're not seeing stuff then the app probably isn't connecting to the internet, which means it's behaving as you described.